# What are the standard values of the GPSMAPDATUM attribute in the exif standard?

Tags: datum, exif

I'm working on an application to read the `exif` georeferenced metadata of some photos.
I would like to know all the possible values of the attribute `GPSMapDAtum`. Do you know where to find a list with all the standard values?

Comment: Probably you should change the question, as it appears you don't want `possible` values, but rather likely or standard values

Answer (score 3):

It's maybe a little unclear, but from page 79 of the May 2019 revision of the EXIF spec, it looks like that can be an arbitrary string of any length:

[image: GPSMapDatum tag description]

It's also not required, only strongly recommended.

[DC-008-Translation-2019-E.pdf](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/328209/what-are-the-standard-values-of-the-gpsmapdatum-attribute-in-the-exif-standard) via Archive.org

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
That documentation is what I had looked at. But the definition is too broad.

Comment: If the definition comes from the official specification how can you call it too broad?

Comment: Because the number of possibilities is very high and it does not follow any standard nomenclature. You can find values like "WGS84" or "WGS-84" ...

Answer (score 1):

A good place to look would be the [EPSG Geodetic Parameter Registry](https://epsg.org/)

A search by *type* (using GeodeticDatum) and *area* (using 'world') gives 34 results:

https://www.epsg-registry.org/report.htm?type=lastQuery&title=&reportDetail=short&style=urn:uuid:report-style:default-with-code&style_name=OGP%20Default%20With%20Code&title=Geodetic%20datums%20with%20global%20coverage&r=34

As for 'standard' values, my Garmin GPSMAP 64s offers me the following datums list:

- Tristan Ast '68
- Viti Levu 1916
- Wake-Eniwetok
- WGS 72
- WGS 84
- Zanderij
- None
- User

Comment: Thank you very much for the information.
What I'm really looking for is if there is a list of standard values.